# Intellij IDEA + SBT: skip download errors for non-existing Sources/Javadocs

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

[In **Intellij IDEA** (2016), with **Download: Sources and Javadocs** enabled, (can't insert image inline due to lack of reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Sz4.png)

**SBT** will attempt to download **Sources** and **Javadocs** for all dependencies, whether or not they exist.

Problem is, when a dependency (or worse, nested dependency) does not have a **Source**/**Javadoc**, the build will fail.

Is there any way to configure **IDEA**/**SBT** to check and skip downloading **Sources**/**Javadocs** if it does not exist, or ignore errors when downloading **Sources**/**Javadocs**, without having to append

```
withSources() withJavadoc()
```

to every dependency?

For example, a dependency relying on **Antlr 2.7.7**, which does not have Javadocs (**antlr-2.7.7-javadoc.jar**) in **Maven Central** (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/), with **Download: Javadoc** enabled, will return error:

```
SBT project import
                [warn]  [FAILED     ] antlr#antlr;2.7.7!antlr.jar(doc):  (0ms)
                [warn] ==== local: tried
                [warn]   C:\Users\Daniel\.ivy2\local\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\docs\antlr-javadoc.jar
                [warn] ==== public: tried
                [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7-javadoc.jar
                [warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
                [warn]   C:\Users\Daniel\.activator\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\docs\antlr-javadoc.jar
                [warn] ==== activator-local: tried
```

Comment: this still happens in intellij 2020.1, sbt 1.3.10

Comment: @shadowchris Seems a very recent problem too. I used the same setup for more than a year now without an issue. I updated sbt version and now it is causing problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Idea Settings > Build ... > Build Tools > sbt: uncheck Download Library sources and sbt sources

Comment: But I still want to `Download Library sources and sbt sources`. Assume we have 30 libs (included transitive deps) and only 1 lib don't have `-sources.jar`. How can we let IntelliJ successfully download the existed sources?

Comment: I don't think this will get properly fixed until this: https://github.com/coursier/sbt-coursier/pull/232 gets merged into coursier and that version of coursier gets merged into sbt.